# Why is my Android ORM library generating these odd strings?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm

I am using [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html) to take objects, and then list them in the ListView that you see below. Instead of listing the strings that I entered in to my database, though, Sugar ORM seems to be generating some sort of resource identifiers instead of strings. Any idea what these are and how I can turn them back into strings?

This is my code for the ListView:

```
    List<Book> books = Select.from(Book.class).orderBy("item").list();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Book>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, books));
```

[image: My List]

Comment: I am not familiar with android, but it seems you have an object that has some characteristic and you have failed to address them with setter or getter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listview is populated with "Book" objects
For every list item the simple_list_item is printing the toString of the Book class. If you do not override the toString it will print out "Class@somenumber" wich is what it doesn in your case.

You can do two things:

Override the toString method of the book class so you can decide what it shows.

example:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    // assuming your book has a title (and its a string), put what you want here
    return getTitle();
}
```

The other option is to make a custom view for your listitem. 
So instead of using the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 you create your own. In the view you might have a tekstview that you can fill with the book title. This is a bit more work, but you also have the most control over the layout of the list items.

Comment: @Gray Thank you for this well-written answer! I'll be trying it when I get home

Comment: I didn't write the answer @PintSizeSlash3r.  I just edited it.  Credit to nikitani. :-)